# When submitting a form, I get a "Cannot Display Page" Error

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form that takes user inputs and writes them into a database. The problem is when they press submit using `<input type="submit" onsubmit="insertData()" >`, instead of the browser loading my "Thank You" page, I get a "Cannot display page" error however if I reload the page there's no issue.

I've tried different things with it like `target="_self", target="_blank", action="url"` but nothing works. Any ideas as to why? Server side settings maybe?

My form tag looks like `<form target="_self"  method="post" id = "questionnaire" class="validate" onsubmit="return submit();">`

Thanks.

Edit

This is the entire code. http://pastebin.com/CX612SSN
The site is for intranet purposes so there's no real security features.

Comment: please show your entire code, html, js

Comment: "Cannot display page" is the browser being fluffy. Find the real error message. It might be a 404. It might be a 500. It might be something else. IIRC: Chrome has a More Info button. IE stuffs it in the title.

Comment: Only `<form>` tags can have `onsubmit` methods, not "submit" buttons.

Comment: Sorry, I meant onclick="insertData()"

Comment: I can't find any submit fonction. Your onsubmit="return submit();" won't work without a function called "submit"

Comment: @user3130127 try to run your code in IE.

Comment: You have created a submit() function? can you post the code? where it is supposed to go the form?

Comment: At one point I created a submit function but then deleted it. Also, the only browser it runs on (without many problems) is IE. According to Microsoft, it may be a server side issue not allowing method="post" but I have no way of checking that